# MySQLDataAdapter Update() function takes a while to just update one row in a specifc bound DataGridView but works fine on others

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 DataGridViews, each bound to a specific table in my MySQL database, when the user changes a cell value in the grid, i use the `CellValidated` event to send the data back to the table using the dataAdapter's `Update()` function.

The odd thing is, there is one of those 3 datagridviews that is taking like 1-2 seconds to update a single record, while the other two do it in a blink of an eye. I'm highly suspecting its because i have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in the problematic grid that receives its `DataSource` from the `BindingSource` of a DIFFERENT DataGridView. The other grids dont have that sort of column.

This is how the problematic grid looks like[image]

The "Mensalistas" tab contains the personal info data of the company clients, and on the "Recibos de Mensalistas" tab i have the problematic grid that is responsible for generating receipts to the company's clients by basing each entry on the "Mensalista" DataGridViewComboBoxColumn there.

That dgv column is bound to a FK (uneeded maybe? since im always making sure that the DB column receives a valid ID from the "Mensalistas" tab/db) indexed column in the DB whose Reference Table and FoireignColumn is the Mensalista.Id field from the Mensalista table that is bound to the "Mensalistas" dataGridView

This is the code that is used on the Form_Load function to fill the problematic datagridView

```
        //DataGridViewRecibosMensalistas
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = AccessControl.BuildMySQLConnection("database");
            connection.Open();

            string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM `recibosmensalistas`;";

            dataAdapterRecibosMensalistas = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection.ConnectionString);

            dataTableRecibosMensalistas = new DataTable();
            dataTableRecibosMensalistas.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapterRecibosMensalistas.Fill(dataTableRecibosMensalistas);

            SendMessage(dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);

            // Prolly the culprit?
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn idMensalista = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            idMensalista.ValueType = typeof(uint);
            idMensalista.DataPropertyName = "IdMensalista";
            idMensalista.HeaderText = "Mensalista";
            idMensalista.Name = "colunaIdMensalista";
            idMensalista.ValueMember = "Id"; // dataAdapter will use the Id field from Mensalistas table to run the update query but...
            idMensalista.DisplayMember = "Nome"; // ...the combobox should display the names in the list, not the Ids, so this is needed
            idMensalista.DataSource = bindingSourceMensalistas; // Fills the comboboxes with data from the mensalistas table (the one that holds personal data info)
            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.Columns.Add(idMensalista);

            DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn colunaDataEmissao = new DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn("00/00/0000");
            colunaDataEmissao.DataPropertyName = "DataEmissao";
            colunaDataEmissao.HeaderText = "Data de Emissão";
            colunaDataEmissao.Name = "colunaDataEmissao";
            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.Columns.Add(colunaDataEmissao);

            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing; //or even better .DisableResizing. Most time consumption enum is DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders
            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas, true);

            bindingSourceRecibosMensalistas = new BindingSource();
            bindingSourceRecibosMensalistas.DataSource = dataTableRecibosMensalistas;

            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.DataSource = bindingSourceRecibosMensalistas;

            dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas.CellFormatting += dataGridView_CellFormatting;

            SendMessage(dataGridViewMensalistas.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);

            connection.Close();
        }
```

And here is the code for the CellValidated event:

```
    private void dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSourceRecibosMensalistas.EndEdit();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridViewRecibosMensalistas[(int)ColumnIndexRecibosMensalistas.COLUNA_ID, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                dataAdapterRecibosMensalistas.Update((DataTable)bindingSourceRecibosMensalistas.DataSource);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {                    
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Occoreu um erro de índice ao validar uma linha de dados.\nPara evitar que esse erro aconteça no futuro, procure preencher ao menos uma célula da linha (de prefeência, a primeira célula da linha).\n\nCaso o erro persista, contate o desenvolvedor do sistema. Erro: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Shitty function i use just to force a rebind in the datagridview in case anything goes wrong 
                    UpdateDataGridViewOnRequest((int)DataGridViewIndex.DATAGRIDVIEW_RECIBOS_MENSALISTAS);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                string message = "Ocorreu um erro de concurrência de dados ao tentar salvar as suas mudanças na linha.\n\n";
                message = message + "Erros de concurrência de dados ocorrem quando uma linha tenta ser alterada ao mesmo tempo por duas ou mais pessoas.\n\n";
                message = message + "As prováveis causas para isso são:\n1) Algum outro usuário editou a linha antes das suas alterações serem salvas.\n2) Falha no banco de dados.\n\n";
                message = message + "A tabela agora será atualizada contendo os valores atuais para a linha, caso o erro persista, contate o desenvolvedor do sistema.\n\n";
                message = message + "Erro: " + ex.Message;
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    UpdateDataGridViewOnRequest((int)DataGridViewIndex.DATAGRIDVIEW_RECIBOS_MENSALISTAS);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe i should try to either remove the FK or/and get the Mensalistas ID and Name fields to populate the combobox in the SELECT command in the code up there instead of using a different binding source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can think of two reasons it will take longer, not sure if you have a try catch on the others but that slows it down. also how big is this table which it is lagging on? bigger tables mean longer wait times to update as it needs to find the row in a larger data set

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, unfortunatelly the datagridview on the third tabcontrol has the exact same size as the one giving the problem, so i dont believe thats the problem. And regarding the try catch, now that you have said it, i forgot to put my CellValidated code on the OP, will do it now.

Comment: are you adding the whole column each time you update? 0.o

Comment: No, the column is added only when form containing the grid is loaded, the column originally comes as a normal textbox column, but i swap it for a ComboBox column type before the binding is actually done.